# What is the data structure of a collection/ordered set in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, set

The Backbone docs says this -

> Collections are ordered sets of models.

But what exactly is an ordered set? I know it's an object but what I don't understand the data structure because it has keys like an object-

```
Object.keys(exampleCollection
//returns ["length", "models", "_byId", "currentSort", "fetched", "_listenerId", "_events", "comparator"]
```

but you can call array functions on it like map-

```
exampleCollection.map(function (mod) {console.log(mod)})
//displays 3 models
```

Comment: a collection stores models in both ways.  Try a console.log of the collection and you will see a _byId object, which is defined by whatever you set id to in the colleection class, and a models array.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying data structure is an array.  Most of the Backbone.Collection methods operate on `this.models` which is an array.  The great thing about Backbone is that it's easy to open it up and take a look at what's under the hood -- especially with their [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-98).

Comment: so it's an obj(hash) which holds an array? when you call methods on the object, it will know to call it on its array attribute?

Comment: Only certain methods, mainly the underscore methods. Check out the backbone website, it's pretty clear.